# getting an integer from a file c++

Tags: c++

How can I read a number from a file using fread fwrite
This is my code

```
char *buff[1];
int highscore;
FILE *FPtr;
FPtr = fopen("highscore.txt","w+");
if(FPtr != NULL){
    fread(buff,sizeof(buff),1, FPtr);

}
if(buff == NULL){
     fprintf (FPtr, "%d" , 10);
     fclose(FPtr);
}
```

So after the initial running where it creates the file and prints 10 into the file 
I want to read the file and then print out the 10
How would I go about doing this??

Comment: Are you allowed to use `fscanf()`?  Is this homework?

Comment: If you're using C++, I would probably use streams.  Anyway, you're looking for fscanf.

Comment: Do you know how it was written? Is the the ascii string '1', '0', '\n' ? Or is it the binary value 0x0000000A ? To ask this another way, what do you see when you edit the file in a text editor?

Comment: I highly highly doubt this is right: `char *buff[1];`  An array of one pointer?

Comment: Also, _always_ check the return values from loading/scanning functions like `fread`

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to read an `int` with `fread`, you don't want to use a separate pointer, you want to use the address of that `int`:

```
int highscore;

fread(&highscore, sizeof(highscore), 1, score_file);
```

To match that, when you do the writing, you want to use `fwrite`:

```
int highscore;

fwrite(&highscore, sizeof(highscore), 1, score_file);
```

Beware, however, that the file won't be portable -- trying (for example) to write it on one machine and read it on another may produce grossly incorrect results. Even re-compiling your code with different options *could* change what the program's implicit idea of the file format (e.g., changing from 32-bit to 64-bit compilation could easily break things).